# Lookup field is not saving when populated by Javascript in Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, lookup

On Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011:

If I set the value of a lookup field using Javascript, it appears correctly on the form (name, icon, etc) but does not save when the user hits the save button.  The record does save, just not that field.  If I do it "manually" (ie - use the lookup control) it will save the field value.

For some reason, it is working in the form's "on Save" event, but it is Not working in the form's "on Save & Close" event. 
Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
//Fetching the required accountId using REST method
function fetchAccountId() {
    try
    {
        var LE;
        var Fund;
        var LEId = new Array();
        LEId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ssi_legalentityid').getValue();   
        if (LEId != null) {
            LE = LEId[0].id;
        }
        var FundId = new Array();
        FundId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ssi_fundid').getValue();    
        if (FundId != null) {
            Fund = FundId[0].id;    
        }

        var LEId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ssi_legalentityid').getValue();
        var FundId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ssi_fundid').getValue();
        var TransactionType = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ssi_transactiontypes').getValue();
        if (LEId != null && FundId != null && TransactionType == '6')
        {       
            var options = "$select=ssi_AccountId,ssi_name&$filter=Ssi_LegalEntityId/Id eq (guid'"+LE+"') and Ssi_FundId/Id eq (guid'"+Fund+"')";            
            SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords('ssi_Account', options, saved, err, contactsRetrieveComplete);
        }   
    }
    catch (Err) {
    alert(Err);
    return;
    }
}
function saved(ssi_account)
{
    if (ssi_account != null && ssi_account.length > 0) 
    {
        var fetchedAccId;
        for (var i = 0; i < ssi_account.length; i++) 
        {
            fetchedAccId = ssi_account[i].ssi_AccountId;
            fetchedName = ssi_account[i].ssi_name;
        }       
        var Contact_Lookup = new Array();
        Contact_Lookup[0] = new Object();
        Contact_Lookup[0].id = fetchedAccId;
        Contact_Lookup[0].name = fetchedName;
        Contact_Lookup[0].entityType = 'ssi_Account';
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ssi_accountid').setValue(Contact_Lookup);
        Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();        
    }
}
function err(error){
    alert('Error occurred while fetching the details of the Client Account. '+error.message);
}
function contactsRetrieveComplete() {
}
```

The above code is called on the Save event of the CRM form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code retrieves the data *onSave* using the CRM SDK function `retrieveMultipleRecords`, which signature is this:

`function (type, options, successCallback, errorCallback, OnComplete)`

Your code passes the `saved` function to the `successCallback` parameter. The `saved` function is called asynchronously. In the *Save* scenario this is OK, but in the *Save and Close* scenario the form is closed and its scripts are disposed before `retrieveMultipleRecords` is able to receive the queried data.

Your code must operate synchronously to succeed.

In the `RetrieveMultipleRecords` function of the `SDK.REST` library you will find these lines:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", this._ODataPath() + type + "Set" + optionsString, true);
```

Change the last `true` into `false`. This will put the function into synchronous mode.

Comment: Hi Henk van Boeijen, 

Thank you for replying. You are right the saved code is called asynchronously. 

How do I make the code operate synchronously in the Form's "Save & Close" event?

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: Hi Henk van Boeijen, i will try this out...Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Try to change line

```
Contact_Lookup[0].entityType = 'ssi_Account';
```

to line

```
Contact_Lookup[0].entityType = 'ssi_account';
```